# Minecraft how update server from 1.8 to 1.9 without losing my world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a vanilla Minecraft 1.8 server world but when I update the server to 1.9 it doesn't re-build the world properly and I cannot find the server from the game menu. How do I update it and keep the world we built?

Comment: Are you sure you're spawning in the same location?  It's possible (although unlikely) that either your spawn or the world changed when you updated to 1.9

Comment: I wasn't spawning at all. I couldn't find the server. However, I've now amended it to log on via my IPv4 which seems to work. I get a warning though "Server can't keep up" so I'm going to look that up next! Thanks!

Comment: How exactly did you update the server? It might be as simple as replacing the server config file for 1.9 with the one you had for 1.8.

Comment: Also, that "Server can't keep up" tells me you probably had a bunch of command block contraptions.  Disable command blocks in the config file by setting `enable-command-block` to `false`.

Answer (score 4):

Just copy the `world` folder from your server folder to another location (if you named him different: just copy the folder where your world is stored).

Make also a copy of the whitelist, banlist and settings file.

Then just make a new server folder. Download the 1.9 JAR file. Start the server. After it is done installing stuff, stop the server. Dont just close it, but type `stop` in the server window.

If the server is off, delete the world folder, the ban/whitelist and the settings file from the new (1.9) server folder.

Last step is just putting the files back you backed up.

Hope the problem is fixed for you. If you have any other questions or need more help, leave a message.